# WAMP : Content not displaying on web page after adding php code

Tags: php, database, google-cloud-firestore, runtime-error, wamp

WAMP / PHP does not display any content on my page when I use this code to insert into Google Firestore Database. No errors are thrown, nothing is inserted to the database and I cannot make an print anything on the page either. No echos or html, but when I remove the block, it reappears. Also I have a class that when instantiated does the same thing and it has similar code to this. Is this a general PHP error? I also turned errors on in my php.ini file.

```
$citiesRef = $db->collection('activites');
$citiesRef->document('dogging')->set([
     'name' => 'San Francisco',
     'state' => 'CA',
     'country' => 'USA',
     'capital' => false,
     'population' => 860000
]);
```

Comment: My guess would be your db connection is not completing.

Comment: @Mech correct but surely it would print something either way though? Or are you saying it will display nothing until it reaches a connection?

Comment: Depends on the rest of the code. Try checking the connection: if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

Comment: @Mech cheers it says connected successfully. Just tried other commands like retrieving from it and it crashes it too

Comment: Dogging as an activity in San Francisco ... wait ... what? Is this like Tinder for casual carpark meetups?

Comment: @CD001 haha.. Volunteering app but need to keep myself sane through stupid activites haha

Comment: please try to run this quickstart [1] in order to know if this an issue with your WAMP environment or some missconfiguration related with datastore client library

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers#php

Comment: @JorgeHDZ whats weird is today I ran "php thefile.php" in a terminal it completed the request. But in WAMP it doesent. I understand there are two different PHP environments (one wamp and one system) however I copied the whole directory from the working one and replaced the wamp one... for some reason it just says the the extension is not installed yet I am able to select it from the WAMP menu as an extension

Comment: @Ronnie Lightweightbaby Coleman, to discard any environment issue or miss-configuration you can try to run it on a VM or in another fresh installation of PHP and composer

Comment: @JorgeHDZ unfortunately that is what I had to do but it eventually fixed it